# Is there a cryptosystem that allows a set of auditors to confirm that they have valid Shamir or Group signatures?

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, key-generation

Suppose I have a client that generates and sends a Shamir key (or group signature) to a set of Auditors.

This key is essentially an unverified set of bytes.  Each auditor wants to somehow verify that the keys are valid, and can be combined.

What technique can be used to ensure that valid (and not garbage) key material was sent to each Auditor?

Answer (score 2):

For [Shamir's secret sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing), the *only* possible method for validating a share is rebuilding the shared secret with enough shares, and see if the result makes sense. There cannot be any other method that does not involve sufficiently many shares to reach the threshold, because that would contradict information theoretic security of the scheme (basically, if you have a way to validate a share, then you can do an exhaustive search on possible shares).

For other algorithms, this is a possible feature that any given algorithm may or may not provide. There is no generic method. One can surmise that [non-interactive zero-knowledge proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-interactive_zero-knowledge_proof) will probably be involved at some point, so the details will not only be specific to the scheme, but also substantially hairy.